# R - How to calculate the frequency of occurence within a specific time step

Tags: r, time, frequency

I have a data frame with a specific variable (Var1) and a time variable (Var2).

I would like to calculate the frequency  of occurrence (Frequency) of Var1 withing a specific time step (let say 1 min) during a year.

sample dataset:

```
Var1 <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 2)) 
Var2 <- c("2018-09-01 10:00:00", "2018-09-01 10:00:30", "2018-09-01 10:00:45", 
    "2018-09-10 22:10:00", "2017-09-05 10:54:30", "2018-12-15 10:00:30", 
    "2018-12-15 10:01:00", "2017-02-20 17:16:30", "2017-12-20 20:08:56") 
df <- data.frame(Var1, Var2) 
df$Var2 <- as.POSIXct(df$Var2)
```

desired output:

```
Frequency <- c(rep(3, 3), rep(1, 2), rep(2,2), rep(1,2)) 
dfOut <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Frequency) 

#  Var1                Var2 Frequency
#1    A 2018-09-01 10:00:00         3
#2    A 2018-09-01 10:00:30         3
#3    A 2018-09-01 10:00:45         3
#4    A 2018-09-10 22:10:00         1
#5    B 2017-09-05 10:54:30         1
#6    B 2018-12-15 10:00:30         2
#7    B 2018-12-15 10:01:00         2
#8    C 2017-02-20 17:16:30         1
#9    C 2017-12-20 20:08:56         1
```

Comment: Sorry I do not really know how to insert the file in the comment :s  So here is the code to generate the dataframe                                            Var1 <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 2))

Var2 <- c("2018-09-01 10:00:00", "2018-09-01 10:00:30", "2018-09-01 10:00:45", "2018-09-10 22:10:00", "2017-09-05 10:54:30", "2018-12-15 10:00:30", "2018-12-15 10:01:00", "2017-02-20 17:16:30",  "2017-12-20 20:08:56")

Frequency <- c(rep(3, 3), rep(1, 2), rep(2,2), rep(1,2))

df <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Frequency)

df$Var2 <- as.POSIXct(df$Var2)

Comment: I don't understand the desired output - how is the frequency given by minute?

Comment: In the first 3 rows, A occurred 3 times within a minute (10:00:00, 10:00:30, 10:00:45). At the row 6 and 7 B occurred 2 times (10:00:30, 10:01:00). Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate::floor_date` to get the minute grouping column that accounts for date as you are describing. Note that your displayed desired output does not seem to match your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271786/r-how-to-calculate-the-frequency-of-occurence-within-a-specific-time-step/52280893#comment91495773_52273437)

```r
Var1 <- c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 2)) 
Var2 <- c("2018-09-01 10:00:00", "2018-09-01 10:00:30", "2018-09-01 10:00:45", 
          "2018-09-10 22:10:00", "2017-09-05 10:54:30", "2018-12-15 10:00:30", 
          "2018-12-15 10:01:00", "2017-02-20 17:16:30", "2017-12-20 20:08:56") 
df <- data.frame(Var1, Var2) 
df$Var2 <- as.POSIXct(df$Var2)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(minute = floor_date(Var2, unit = "minute")) %>%
  add_count(Var1, minute)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>   Var1  Var2                minute                  n
#>   <fct> <dttm>              <dttm>              <int>
#> 1 A     2018-09-01 10:00:00 2018-09-01 10:00:00     3
#> 2 A     2018-09-01 10:00:30 2018-09-01 10:00:00     3
#> 3 A     2018-09-01 10:00:45 2018-09-01 10:00:00     3
#> 4 A     2018-09-10 22:10:00 2018-09-10 22:10:00     1
#> 5 B     2017-09-05 10:54:30 2017-09-05 10:54:00     1
#> 6 B     2018-12-15 10:00:30 2018-12-15 10:00:00     1
#> 7 B     2018-12-15 10:01:00 2018-12-15 10:01:00     1
#> 8 C     2017-02-20 17:16:30 2017-02-20 17:16:00     1
#> 9 C     2017-12-20 20:08:56 2017-12-20 20:08:00     1
```

Created on 2018-09-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Create a new character vector to define the groups, then group by Var1 and the new variable. This doesn't give exactly your desired output because the minutes are defined differently.

```
    library(dplyr)
    df %>% 
      mutate(minute = substring(as.character(Var2), 1, 16)) %>% 
      group_by(Var1, minute) %>% 
      mutate(frequency = n())
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I include the date too? This solution takes in consideration the time (minute) to define groups but not the date. is it possible to group per time and date?

Comment: If you do as.character(as.POSIXct("2017-12-20 20:08:56")), like you do in your example, you get a character string including the date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` approach. You can first create an index showing if the datetime for next row is 1 min after the datetime of current row. Then, use this as one of the grouping criteria to calculate the frequency.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, idx := cumsum(c(0L, Var2[-1L] > Var2[-.N] + 60L)), by=.(Var1)][, 
    Freq := .N, by=.(Var1, idx)]
```

output:

```
   Var1                Var2 idx Freq
1:    A 2018-09-01 10:00:00   0    3
2:    A 2018-09-01 10:00:30   0    3
3:    A 2018-09-01 10:00:45   0    3
4:    A 2018-09-10 22:10:00   1    1
5:    B 2017-09-05 10:54:30   0    1
6:    B 2018-12-15 10:00:30   1    2
7:    B 2018-12-15 10:01:00   1    2
8:    C 2017-02-20 17:16:30   0    1
9:    C 2017-12-20 20:08:56   1    1
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution is almost what i would like to do but it does take in consideration the time (minute) to define groups but not the date. is it possible to group per time and date?

Comment: Not so sure what output you are describing here. Can you add to your desired output to the question?

Comment: For example, if at the row 6 you have 2018-01-23 10:00:30 and at the row 7 you have 2018-12-15 10:01:00, the Freq should not be 2 at the row 6 and 7. Is it clearer?

Comment: Second concern, I tested the code but if I remove the variable Frequency I got an error and idx = NA for some row, why? Frequency is the output variable it should not affect the code if I remove it, should not it?

Comment: If you don’t post any data that is causing the error, I cannot make any sense of what you are talking about.